# Is there a way to remove black background color around numbers?

Tags: c, bgi

I'm printing numbers through loop. I want to remove the black background around numbers. is there a way to do it?

```
void Game_Play() {
    setcolor(BROWN);
    setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,7);
    bar(150, 100, 550, 420);
    setlinestyle(0, 0, 4); 

    rectangle(150, 100, 550, 420);
    setcolor(8); 
    line(250, 100, 250, 420);
    line(350, 100, 350, 420);
    line(450, 100, 450, 420);
    line(150,180 , 550, 180);
    line(150,260 , 550, 260);
    line(150,340 , 550, 340);
    setcolor(RED);
    settextstyle(10, 0, 5); 

    for(int i=0,k=1,y=120;i<4;i++,y+=80)
    {   for(int j=0,x=190;j<4;j++,k++,x+=100)
        {
            char num[100];
            sprintf(num,"%d",k);
            outtextxy(x,y,num);
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

[image: OUTPUT of program]

Comment: What library are those functions from?

Comment: Looks like [BGI](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/) maybe. So probably [setbkcolor()](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/setbkcolor.html) would work.

Comment: ... `setbkcolor(7)` to match what the `bar()` did.

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually really using `<graphics.h>` or `<winbgim.h>`, you probably should *seriously* consider moving up to a more modern graphics capability.

However, for the code in your question, you need to call the `setbkcolor()` function, if memory serves:

```
...
setcolor(RED);
settextstyle(10, 0, 5);
setbkcolor(7);
...
```

Comment: Thanks, man. It was just a limitation given by our teacher. that's why using graphics.h library

Comment: @AhmadAminFarooq do not tag `[graphics]` for `graphics.h` instead use `[BGI]` or `[WinBGI]` as `graphics.h` include file is very common filename among many libs and tells us nothing... `[graphics]` tag has different meaning than to represent ancient gfx lib